# Internal *current value* of Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-2016

I'm creating an array that iterates asynchronously (for fun).  This works fine:

```
class AsyncArray extends Array {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.x = 0;
    }

    [Symbol.iterator]() {
        return {
            next: () => {
                let promise = new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(
                    () => resolve(this.x++), 1000)
                );
                return {done: this.x >= this.length, value: promise};
            }
        };
    }
}

async () => {
    for (let x of AsyncArray.of(1, 2, 3)) {
        let value = await x;
        console.log(value);
    }
}();
```

However, this prints out `0...1...2` because I'm keeping track of the current counter on my own and initializing it to `x`.

Is there any way to get the current iterator *value* internal to the Array? I would also need to be able to properly determine the `done` value.

Comment: Do you want to resolve with `x` or with `this[x]`?

Comment: @Bergi using `this[x]` makes perfect sense and solves the problem.

Comment: Oops, looks like I didn't understand your question, I thought your problem was that you had to use a custom counter…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you don't want the counter internal to your array, but rather to your iterator. Use a local variable in the method for that:

```
[Symbol.iterator]() {
    var x = 0;
    return {
        next: () => {
            let promise = new Promise(resolve =>
                setTimeout(() => resolve(this[x++]), 1000)
            );
            return {done: x >= this.length, value: promise};
        }
    };
}
```

The easiest way to write iterators though is by using a generator function:

```
[Symbol.iterator]*() {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.length; x++)
         yield new Promise(resolve =>
             setTimeout(() => resolve(this[x]), 1000)
         );
}
```

That will take care of the correct `done` value as well (and won't "`return`" a promise that resolves with `undefined`).

---

An alternative that would completely avoid tracking state in a local variable or instance property would be to make use of the standard array iterator:

```
[Symbol.iterator]() {
    var vals = super[Symbol.iterator]();
    var it = Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(vals)); // an array iterator
    it.next = () => {
        var res = vals.next();
        if (!res.done)
            return {done: false, value: new Promise(resolve =>
                setTimeout(() => resolve(res.value), 1000)
            )};
        return res;
    };
    return it;
}
```